# Remove an element from an index in an array

Tags: java, jquery, arrays, element

I have a question where i have to remove a  an array. for example;

```
  2 (3, 5, 6)
```

In this case in th array
.

For example, i have to implement this defintion in my main class,

Answer (score 1):

The code for this problem could be heavily optimized, but assuming we want an answer that is easier to understand, here is some java code to replace a word with it's synonym, **no input is validated**, so will fail if using null values:

```
public class SynonymHandler {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] synonymData = { "merciful", "gracious", "kindly", "forgiving" };
        System.out.println("# original");
        for (String element : synonymData) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }

        String[] modified = removeSynonym(synonymData, "merciful", "gracious");
        System.out.println("# modified");
        for (String element : modified) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }

    private static String[] removeSynonym(String[] synonymData, String word, String synonym) {
        // result will have the same length as source:
        String[] result = new String[synonymData.length];

        // loop through the synonymData
        for (int index = 0; index < synonymData.length; index++) {
        // if word = synonymData[index] use synomyn, else use the original value
            result[index] = word.equals(synonymData[index]) ? synonym : synonymData[index];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a very strange way to store the data. Is that your design or one you were handled? It would make more sense to store either a HashMap of Strings (the word) to arrays of strings (the synonyms). But let's work with what you have.

It looks like your synonym data is being passed in as an array of simple strings -- just like they appear when you printed them -- rather than parsed into a better format. So `synonymData[0]` is the data for `merciful` and `synonynData[1]` is the data for `powerful`. After that, it's free format text.

Let's look at your code:

```java
public static void removeSynonym(String[] synonymData, String word, String synonym) {
    int index = synonymLineIndex(synonymData, word);
    String[] removedSynData = new String[synonymData.length];
    for (int i = 0, int m = 0; i < synonymData.length; i++)
        if (synonymData[index].contains(word))
            removedSynData[m++] = synonymData[i];
}
```

Your code never modifies synonymData. It creates a new removedSynData array, builds it out, and then proceeds to dump it on the floor, not doing anything with it. Furthermore, it's not in the same style as the original structure.

There are two basic approaches you can take. First, you get the right index when you do this:

```java
    int index = synonymLineIndex(synonymData, word);
```

**Method One: Parse Line, Remove, Rebuild Line**

Method one would involve parsing this line -- making a string array of the synonyms, then removing the one you're trying to remove, then rebuilding a new string.

Do do that you could do:

```java
   String[] bigParts = synonymData[index].split("\\|");
```

After this, `bigParts[0]` contains the word (possibly with white space) and `bigParts[1]` contains all the synonyms as a single string (possibly with white space). Note that `split()` takes a regular expression, which is why I included the `\\`. So it passes a single `\` to split, to escape the pipe character that would otherwise stand for OR.

You'll want to check the length of the array is at least 2 then do:

```java
   String[] synonyms = bigParts[1].split(",");
```

You can run through the array, trim them of white space, and then look for the one you want to remove it. Remove it from the array. Then reassemble a string (code of you to figure out), and do this:

```java
   synonymData[index] = YourNewString;
```

**Method Two: ReplaceAll()**

The other approach would be to just use a regular expression with `String.replaceAll()`. It would need to be a sorta complicated RE to make sure you only match the entire word. For instance, if you're supposed to remove `rent` you wouldn't want to match `parent`. That will take time to figure out, but when you're done, it's a single line of code.

```java
   synonymData[index] = synonymData[index].replaceAll("The big RE");
```